# Why output current shoots up by 10x

Tags: current, inductor, buck

Here is my hand cranked generator for charging a high voltage capacitor. How the system is designed to work is shown in the following image: [image]

It is designed to charge the 10 mF capacitor to upto 50 V and to provide 5 V at 100 mA. While testing the output of the circuit by connecting an LED with a resistor in series, a strange behavior is noted: When the capacitor voltage is 50 V and discharged through the 3.5 V LED and an 82 ohm resistor, the current through the LED is limited to around 18 mA which is what I am looking for until the voltage drops to around 34 - 35 V when the current shoots up to 150 mA and stays that way till the cap is completely discharged. When it is again charged to around 30 - 31 V, it exhibits the same behavior when voltage reaches to 26 - 27 V. The similar behavior can be seen at different voltages of charge-discharge cycle. What is this strange behavior? Can it be something to do with the inductor?

Thanks.

**Add1:** Image edited. Here is the datasheet [link](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3639fd.pdf). While it is mentioned in the datasheet to use ferrite pot-core inductor or toroid type inductor, I managed to get DR type inductor of 470 uH value which just looks like this:

[image].

**Add2:** I am not having oscilloscope so I don't know the exact behavior. But, I have noted the following.

***Condition:*** Capacitor is charged to about 30 V.

**Case 1:** Nothing is connected at the output. Almost same voltage as that of the capacitor.

**Case 2:** Only resistor at the output. I see only 1.5 V at the output with the current remaining unchanged at around 18 mA. When the voltage drops below 26 - 27 V, the output current rises to more than 150 mA and the voltage rises to more than 15 V.

**Case 3:** Resistor with LED at the output. Around 18 mA at 5 V. Similar behavior when voltage drops below 26 - 27 V.

Comment: Your converter might be going unstable, have you looked at the waveforms with a scope? Vout, switch node, etc?

Comment: Huh?  What's "o/p"?  Use real words, not baby talk.

Comment: @omsai: Read the downvote button text. I would bet its about the unclear part there. I have no idea what happens when and where.

Comment: Okay. What is unclear here? What have I missed here? Thanks.

Comment: For one thing, you keep talking about an LED and 82-ohm resistor. But no LED or 82-ohm resistor is shown in your schematic. For another you keep talking about things like "the 10 mF capacitor" when you should be putting designators on your schematic and talking about "C1", "D2", etc.

Comment: For another, please give us a link to the datasheet for LTC3639, so we don't have to go search it up ourselves; and tell us exactly what part you used (and give us a datasheet link) for the 470 uH inductor.

Comment: And, when you say "the current shoots up to 150 mA", you need to tell us which current you mean. The current through the LED (which isn't even on your schematic)? The current through the switch? The current through the transformer primary?

Comment: My apologies. Although I have mentioned about the current in the "Question", I have edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: What strange sort of LED will do that I wonder? Data sheet please.

Comment: Do you have a 'scope?  Do you see a jump in the output voltage  ?  What about if you replace the LED with a resistor?

Comment: Added more information.